# Jquery onClick event and multi event data for same classes

Tags: jquery, onclick

How can extract in Jquery "data" value from this:

```
<a href="#" data="12" class="virus">12</a>
<a href="#" data="123" class="virus">another but no 123</a>
<a href="#" data="124" class="virus">need number from data=""</a>
```

to onClick event from each of these anchor with same classes? Thank you:).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$('.virus').click(function() {


  alert($(this).attr('data'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data="12" class="virus">12</a>
<a href="#" data="123" class="virus">another but no 123</a>
<a href="#" data="124" class="virus">need number from data=""</a>
```

use : [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

> Description: Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements.

I suggest you make the `data="12"` into something like `data-data="12"` since data is not a valid attr.

Using [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

> Description: Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements.

Then you can get it like

```
$(this).data('data')
```

Answer (score 2):

Using attr you can data data value. Try this:

```
$(".virus").click(function() {
    var data = $(this).attr("data"); // this will return data value of clicked link
    console.log(data)
});
```